# ShowAllData fails when excel data set is filtered

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I have an ETL file that has suddenly stopped working on the ShowAllData command. In previous loops, the data **IS** being filtered.

**Givens:**

wkstSourceSheet is established in another module as the sheet that contains oSourceTable which is the originating table of data and/or scrubbed data to be uploaded. The steps are contained in functions, grouped logically by module. All local controls are contained in the Local_Controls module.

**Loop Steps**

- Remove any Sorts & Filters on Data (it is on 2nd loop when this fails)
- Apply new Sorts & Filters
- Save Destination File if one is open and destination file is different for this loop
- Open Destination File if needed
- Clear applicable data from Destination
- Paste new data to Destination
- Clear some variables
- Loop

**Code**

```
If wkstSourceSheet.FilterMode = True Then
    wkstSourceSheet.ShowAllData
End If
```

I've been able to get a workaround by replacing it with this

```
If wkstSourceSheet.FilterMode = True Then
    oSoureSheet.Range.Autofilter
    oSoureSheet.Range.Autofilter
End If
```

However, I'm trying to figure out why it would fail when the data is clearly filtered.

Answer (score 0):

(I would write this as a comment if I could... but I don't have enough reputation yet)

Could you be having a problem with the two different types of Autofilters that Excel has?

One for simple Worksheet ranges, the other for ListObjects (Excel "tables").

If there was manual user interaction with the worksheet (not just your code running), a user might have started the filters in two different ways...

Comment: As far as I was able to determine, it seemed to be related to the oSourceSheet object getting caught up in which workbook to use (despite oSourceSheet being established with the workbook object in the set statement). For about a week, it worked that qualifying wbkSource.oSourceSheet fixed the problem. Then, inexplicably, it broke again. I finally had to add a new function after pasting the data but before clearing the variables and reversed the filter opposite the way it was originally created.